# jQuery Selector Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I have the following code..

```
<span class="under"> 
texthere
    <ul class="list">
        <li> list text here</li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

When i run `$(".under").text()` I get "textherelist text here" .

I've tried `$(".under :not(.list)").text()` and get underfined.

I also dont get the correct output for `$(".under").not(".list").text()`

So my last attemp was `$(".list").parent().text()`

which results in textherelist text here

Where am i going wrong with something so simple?

p.s. doesn't have to be jQuery can be JavaScript if its simpler.

Wanted result: texthere

Comment: You're not saying what you want to get as a result, just what the result of different selectors is. Please specify your desired result.

Comment: I'm guessing just the text, not the elements.

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> Description: Get the combined text contents of each element in the set
>   of matched elements, including their descendants.

So yes, that behavior is expected.

You can try this to get only the immediate text node of a selector:

```
$('.under').contents().filter(function(){ return(this.nodeType == 3); }).text()
```

Explanation:

`.contents()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)) returns the children of a selector, including textnodes

> Description: Get the children of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, including text and comment nodes.

`.filter()` takes a callback to return only things you need, based on this, you are only taking those with `nodeType == 3`, which is a text node.

http://jsfiddle.net/R4Pzf/

Comment: Very nice answer defo +1 , one more question whats more elegant and better preformance yours or the answer with clone()? and why?

Comment: This will be much faster, as just using a filter will beat cloning every time as far as I know, but you can test it in jsperf to check for your self. As for more elegant, that's up to the beholder I guess ?

Answer (score 3):

So I'm guessing you're after the text : `texthere` ?

```
var elem = $(".under").clone(),
    text = $.trim(elem.children().remove().end().text());
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/G774V/)

Clone the element, remove all children elements and get the remaining text.
​

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
var text = $('.under').contents(':not(.list)').text();
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ak4FU/1/